# cast char array to integer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char, int

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    unsigned char a[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    int b = *(int *)&a[0];

    printf("%d\n", b);
    return 0;
}
```

I just cannot understand why the result of `b` is `0x4030201`.

Could someone help me out?

Comment: `b` is not `0x4030201`, did you mean `int b = *(int *)&a[0];`?

Comment: Yes, I typed wrongly. Thanks. I have changed it

Comment: What you wrote is undefined behaviour. To do it right, you should say: `int b; unsigned char * a = (unsigned char *)&b;` (And remove your line that declares `b`.)

Comment: @KerrekSB, how does that help convert a "char array to integer"?

Comment: @Zboson: You can write back to the individual bytes that way. I didn't quite spell that out. `a[0] = 1;` etc.

Comment: @KerrekSB, and what if you only want to read from `a` but not write to it? E.g. if `a` is a parameter from a function.

Comment: @Zboson: Ugh, wait, too much confusion. The point is this: to "interpret a char array as an int", you 1) make an int, 2) access its bytes one by one, 3) write the given array values into these new bytes, 4) read the int you made in step 1.

Comment: @KerrekSB, as I understand you are talking about a copy not a cast (not a reinterpret). I actually want exactly what the OP gets (`0x4030201`) but I don't want UB using `int b = *(int *)&a[0]`. I guess I have to use a union but it's not working. Anyway, if I don't get it right I'll ask a question, for now i'm sticking to `int b = *(int *)&a[0]`.

Comment: @Zboson: Well, what I'm trying to say is that you cannot have what you're asking for. Only ints can be ints, nothing else can be an int. The next best thing is what I described.

Answer (score 16):

When you tell the compiler to create an array like this:

```
unsigned char a[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

These numbers are put somewhere in memory in following order:

```
MemoryAddress0: 0x01 -> a[0]
MemoryAddress1: 0x02 -> a[1]
MemoryAddress2: 0x03 -> a[2]
MemoryAddress3: 0x04 -> a[3]
```

`&a[0]` is a `char` pointer with the value of `MemoryAddress0` and points a 1 byte value of `0x01`

`(int*)&a[0]` is a casted pointer with the same value of `MemoryAddress0` but with `int*` type this time so it points to four consecutive bytes.

Most machines we use in our daily lives are *little endian* which means that they store multibyte values in memory from the least significant byte to the most significant one.

When an `int*` points to a memory of four bytes, the first byte it encounters is the least significant byte and the second byte is the the second least significant and so on.

```
MemoryAddress0: 0x01 -> 2^0 term
MemoryAddress1: 0x02 -> 2^8 term
MemoryAddress2: 0x03 -> 2^16 term
MemoryAddress3: 0x04 -> 2^24 term
```

Thus the 4-byte integer value becomes `0x01*2^0 + 0x02*2^8 + 0x03*2^16 + 0x04*2^24` which is equal to `0x04030201`.

Answer (score 6):

You are on a little-endian machine, this means that integers with sizes larger than a byte store the least-significant bytes first.

Note that most architectures these days are little-endian thanks to the common-ness of x86.

Comment: So if I were using a big-endian machine, the result will be 0x1020304?

Comment: Little-Endian machines store the least-significant *bytes*, not bits, first. Is this a typo?

Comment: @Learner and it should 0x01020304 if trion is right, which I think he is.

Answer (score 1):

Because your system is little endian. The first byte in a multi-byte integer is interpreted as the least significant byte in little endian systems.